# break paragraph into sentences in python and link back to an ID

Tags: python, split, sentence

I have two lists, one with ids and one with corresponding comments for each id.

```
list_responseid = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'] 

list_paragraph = [['I like working and helping them reach their goals.'],
 ['The communication is broken.',
  'Information that should have come to me is found out later.'],
 ['Try to promote from within.'],
 ['I would relax the required hours to be available outside.',
  'We work a late night each week.']]
```

The ResponseID 'id1' is related to the paragraph ('I like working and helping them reach their goals.') and so on.

I can break paragraph into sentences using the following function:

```
list_sentence = list(itertools.chain(*list_paragraph))
```

What would be the syntax to get the end result that is data frame (or list) with separate entry for a sentence and have an ID associated with that sentence (which is now linked to paragraph). The final result would look like this (I will convert list to panda data frame at the end).

```
id1 'I like working with students and helping them reach their goals.'
id2 'The communication from top to bottom is broken.'
id2 'Information that should have come to me is found out later and in some cases students know more about what is going on than we do!'
id3 'Try to promote from within.'
id4 'I would relax the required 10 hours to be available outside of 8 to 5 back to 9 to 5 like it used to be.'
id4 'We work a late night each week and rarely do students take advantage of those extended hours.'
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's up with all these 1-element lists?

Comment: When you want an "association" like that I'd suggest a mapping class like `dict`, so something like `dict(zip(list_responseid, [lp[0] for lp in list_paragraph]))` might work.

Comment: dict does return some results, but it is incomplete, it skipped some sentences. Thanks for the hint though, I will keep looking.

Comment: Then just `dict(zip(list_responseid, list_paragraph))`

Comment: I can see that, when I remove 0 it shows all sentences. Now, if I need it structured like a data frame with one record per sentence and ID associated with it, I would need to loop through each value in this dictionary, correct?

Comment: I wouldn't -- just do that in the comp instead: `[(id, sentence) for id, paragraph in zip(list_responseid, list_paragraph) for sentence in paragraph]`, which is basically what your answer is doing down there but with different variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it often it would be clearer, and probably more efficient depending on the size of the arrays, if you make a dedicated function for that with two regular nested loops, but if you need a quick one liner for it (it's doing just that):

```
id_sentence_tuples = [(list_responseid[id_list_idx], sentence) for id_list_idx in range(len(list_responseid)) for sentence in list_paragraph[id_list_idx]]
```

id_sentence_tuples will then be a list of tupples where each of the elements is a pair like (paragraph_id, sentence) just as the result you expect.
Also i would advise you to check that both lists have the same length before doing it so in case they don't you get a meaningful error.

```
if len(list_responseid) != len(list_paragraph):
    IndexError('Lists must have same cardinality')
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. '

Answer (score 0):

I had a dataframe with an ID and a review (col = ['ID','Review']). If you can combine these lists to make a dataframe then you can use my approach. I split these reviews into sentences using nltk and then linked back the IDs within the loop. Following is the code that you can use.

```
## Breaking feedback into sentences
import nltk
count = 0
df_sentences = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    feedback = row['Reviews']
    sent_text = nltk.sent_tokenize(feedback) # this gives us a list of sentences
    for j in range(0,len(sent_text)):
        # print(index, "-", sent_text[j])
        df_sentences = df_sentences.append({'ID':row['ID'],'Count':int(count),'Sentence':sent_text[j]}, ignore_index=True)
        count = count + 1
print(df_sentences)
```